# How to find DB2 tables that do not exist

Tags: sql, db2, catalog

I have a list of tables, and I want to check which ones do not currently exist in the target database, I can't figure out a query to return only the tables from the list that do not exist? I am running DB2 9.7.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the list of tables you want to check against is in a form that you can query it would be something like this.  The query below will return all tables NOT in the select table query (that you'll have to provide):

```
select * from sysibm.systables
where owner = 'SCHEMA'
and type = 'T'
and name not in ( /* select query to return your list of tables */ );
```

---

**Update post comment:**

If the tables are listed in a flat file (.txt, .csv) and the number is manageable.  You should be able to list them out in a coma seperated form like this (at least you can with other sql languages I'm more familiar with).

```
select * from sysibm.systables
where owner = 'SCHEMA'
and type = 'T'
and name not in ( 'table1', 'table2', 'table3', 'table4', 'tableA', 'tableB' );
```

Otherwise you might have to build a quick temp table to import all the table names into and go with the first example still.

---

**Update post post comment:**

And finally, after your most recent comment, *I realize I was mis-understanding your question and had it backwards*.  To flip it and find the tables from the list that aren't in the SCHEMA you'd do something like this.  (after importing the list into a temporary table).

```
select mytablename from templistoftables
where mytablename not in 
(select name from sysibm.systables
where owner = 'SCHEMA'
and type = 'T');
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it is in a .txt file :-( I have a list of tables I'm creating from an Oracle source, which I can't query... I need to find out which ones have not been created yet, and have only an export form the source.

Comment: Updated my answer with more info.

Comment: I think the temp table would be better- in your example it will return all tables except those in the list. I need to know which tables are not there, and ended up writing a quick java applet that will do it. Thanks for your input!

Comment: Ahhhh, I get what your saying... sorry about that.  It's a late night and I'm not thinking strait.  I added another query.